# Google Cloud Endpoints does not restrict access to my API

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-endpoints

I've followed the google cloud endpoints with Google Kubernetes engine tutorial here: https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/get-started-kubernetes-engine
using my own docker image. The Kubernetes part works fine and I can access my services via the loadbalancer IP.

However, when I try to put my service behind cloud endpoints in order to secure it, the endpoint remains public and can be accessed without an API key. Here is my `openapi.yaml`, deployed with `gcloud endpoints services deploy openapi.yaml`:

```
swagger: "2.0"
info:
  description: "A test."
  title: "API test"
  version: "1.0.0"
host: "<test-api.endpoints.MY-PROJECT-ID.cloud.goog>"
x-google-endpoints:
- name: "<test-api.endpoints.MY-PROJECT-ID.cloud.goog>"
  target: "<MY LOADBALANCER IP>"
#require an API key to access project
security:
  - api_key: []
paths:
  /:
    get:
      summary: Return django REST default page
      description: test
      operationId: test
      responses:
        "200":
          description: OK
securityDefinitions:
  # This section configures basic authentication with an API key.
  api_key:
    type: "apiKey"
    name: "key"
    in: "query"
```

When I try to access my service via the value for `host` (obscured because it is still open), it is still open and does not require an API key . Nothing is shown in the cloud endpoints logs either. As far as I understand, the configuration of `openapi.yaml` alone should be enough to restrict access?

Comment: Are you sure you are exposing the proxy (ESP) in your kubernetes service and not your backend directly? Please share your kubernetes service spec.

Comment: @nareddyt I've fixed it now and that was exactly the case. It kind of glossed over it  in the google guide (https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/get-started-kubernetes), but the Kubernetes deployment script pulls an ESP image, which it uses to receive incoming API calls and redirect them to services running in other containers.

Answer (score 0):

Following this page (https://swagger.io/docs/specification/2-0/authentication/api-keys/), your security is misplaced. It should looks like this:

```
swagger: "2.0"
info:
  description: "A test."
  title: "API test"
  version: "1.0.0"
host: "<test-api.endpoints.MY-PROJECT-ID.cloud.goog>"
x-google-endpoints:
- name: "<test-api.endpoints.MY-PROJECT-ID.cloud.goog>"
  target: "<MY LOADBALANCER IP>"
#require an API key to access project
paths:
  /:
    get:
      security:
        - api_key: []
      summary: Return django REST default page
      description: test
      operationId: test
      responses:
        "200":
          description: OK
securityDefinitions:
  # This section configures basic authentication with an API key.
  api_key:
    type: "apiKey"
    name: "key"
    in: "query"
```

**Edit:**

In case you want the api-key in the header, you have to change the definition but you can leave security in the place you declared:

```
swagger: "2.0"
info:
  description: "A test."
  title: "API test"
  version: "1.0.0"
host: "<test-api.endpoints.MY-PROJECT-ID.cloud.goog>"
x-google-endpoints:
- name: "<test-api.endpoints.MY-PROJECT-ID.cloud.goog>"
  target: "<MY LOADBALANCER IP>"
#require an API key to access project
security:
  - api_key: []
paths:
  /:
    get:
      summary: Return django REST default page
      description: test
      operationId: test
      responses:
        "200":
          description: OK
securityDefinitions:
  # This section configures basic authentication with an API key.
  api_key:
    type: "apiKey"
    name: "key"
    in: "header"
```

I didn't understand which version you preferred, so I adjusted both.

Comment: The swagger definition in the original question is valid, my question is about why google cloud endpoints still exposes an my API without requiring an API key